# addTarget adding extra events

Tags: ios, swift, addtarget

I want to add another events when the button is clicked. i use addTarget to observe the button when is clicked and call a method name showModal. see the code below.

```
headerView.addTaskButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showModal), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and i want to add another action when that button is pressed. but i don’t know where.

```
self.todoListViewModel.updateMode(.edit)
```

is there any way to do it with addTarget? like adding closure and stuff?

- I want only addTaskButton to update the mode.
  if i added `self.todoListViewModel.updateMode(.edit)` in showModal method, everything calling that method will be updated the mode as .edit

so i don’t want to put that in showModal method. is there anyway?

Comment: Your question is confusing... Do you have **two** buttons or only **one**? If only one, do you want to execute `self.todoListViewModel.updateMode(.edit)` when the button is *pressed* (`.touchDownInside`), and `showModal()` when the button is released (`.touchUpInside`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 actions declared :

```
func commonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // code for all buttons
}
func showModal(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.todoListViewModel.updateMode(.edit)
    self.commonAction(sender)
}
```

Another option : set the tag of the button to know if you must do the action :

```
func commonActionOrModal(_ sender: UIButton) {
    If sender.tag == 1 {
        self.todoListViewModel.updateMode(.edit)
    }
    // code for all buttons
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add another action, just place your code in "showModal" function

```
func showModal(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
   self.todoListViewModel.updateMode(.edit)

   // your remaining code

}
```

Comment: i don’t want to updateMode for another calling action. like i only want that addTaskButton to only update the mode.

i try to get #func as a parameter to know which calls the method, but error occured.